# How do I make my program wait for NSOpenPanel to close?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

Like the title states, I need to make my program wait until my `NSOpenPanel` closes.  I have the panel open in `windowControllerWillLoadNib` so that it happens before my document window opens. But what happens is that, it just loads both windows without waiting for the panel to close.  How can I make it wait until the open panel is closed and completely finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use runModal method.

Code example:

```
int result;
NSOpenPanel *oPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
result = [oPanel runModalForDirectory:NSHomeDirectory() file:nil types:nil];
if (result == NSOKButton) {
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set up your open panel and then you can do something like this:

```
if ([openPanel runModal]==NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
    // get the urls
    NSArray *fileURLs = [openPanel URLs];
} else {
    // cancel button was clicked
}
```

runModal stops the execution of your program until the panel closes.