# Getting filename from NSOpenPanel dialog

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode6

It's been a year since I last played with Cocoa and it seems a lot has changed.

I am trying to run an open dialog and retrieve the file path.  This used to be very simple but now...

The code is:

```
-(NSString *)getFileName{
NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
__block NSString *returnedFileName;

// This method displays the panel and returns immediately.
// The completion handler is called when the user selects an
// item or cancels the panel.
[panel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result){
    if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
        NSURL* theDoc = [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

        // Open  the document.
        returnedFileName = [theDoc absoluteString];
    }
}];
return returnedFileName;
}

-(IBAction)openAFile:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"openFile Pressed");

NSString* fileName = [self getFileName];

NSLog(@"The file is: %@", fileName);
}
```

(The indentation has been screwed up in the post but it's correct in the code)

My problem is that the final NSLog statement is being executed as soon as the open dialog opens and not waiting until the dialog closes.  That leaves the fileName variable null which is what the final NSLog reports.

What is causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a similar question to yours:
[How do I make my program wait for NSOpenPanel to close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369210/how-do-i-make-my-program-wait-for-nsopenpanel-to-close)

Maybe

```
[openPanel runModal]
```

helps you. It waits until the user closes the panel

Comment: Thanks Christoph.  That combined with a bit of pruning of, what I assume is code bloat on apples part, sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

The stuff I had written a year ago used runModal so on Christoph's advice I went back to that.

It would appear that the beginWithCompletionHandler block is unnecessary, at least in this case.  Removing it also had the advantage of removing the necessity to  use the __block identifier.

The following now works as required

```
-(NSString *)getFileName{
    NSOpenPanel* panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
    NSString *returnedFileName;

    // This method displays the panel and returns immediately.
    // The completion handler is called when the user selects an
    // item or cancels the panel.

    if ([panel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK) {
        NSURL* theDoc = [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];

        // Open  the document.
        returnedFileName = [theDoc absoluteString];
    }

return returnedFileName;
}
```

And well done Apple for deprecating the obvious and easy and replacing it with increased complexity.