# Problems with Replacing NSOpenPanel runModalForDirectory: with beginWithCompletionHandler:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am having problems replacing the deprecated `NSOpenPanel runModalForDirectory:` with the newer `beginWithCompletionHandler:`.

The results are not as expected.  It looks like `beginWithCompletionHandler:` does NOT wait for the user to finish with his or her selection!

Please let me know what I am doing wrong or suggest a different solution for replacing the deprecated method.

```
if ([destpath isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        long result;  
        NSOpenPanel *oPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
        [oPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
        [oPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
        [oPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
        
        result = [oPanel runModalForDirectory:NSHomeDirectory() file:nil types:nil];
        if (result == NSModalResponseOK) 
        {
            destpath = [[oPanel URL] retain].path;
            NSLog(@"destpath is : %@", destpath);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
    
    NSLog(@"MADE IT HERE!! -- destpath is : %@", destpath);
```

I replaced the code with:

```
if ([destpath isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        // long result;  // FIXED!!  Changed int to long
        NSOpenPanel *oPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
        [oPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
        [oPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
        [oPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
                
        [oPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
            if(result == NSModalResponseOK) {
                destpath = [[oPanel URL] retain].path;
                NSLog(@"destpath is : %@", destpath);
                }
            else
                return;
        }];
        
    }
    
    NSLog(@"MADE IT HERE!! -- destpath is : %@", destpath);
```

When I run the original code, I see the following NSLog messages:

```
022-09-04 12:20:18.175924-0400 iRipCD[69097:3332748] destpath is : /Users/grinch/Downloads
2022-09-04 12:20:18.175982-0400 iRipCD[69097:3332748] MADE IT HERE!! -- destpath is : /Users/grinch/Downloads
```

But the new code does not work.  The program does NOT wait for the user to finish with his or her selection of the desired directory. I see the following NSLog messages:

```
2022-09-04 12:15:30.595589-0400 iRipCD[68991:3329339] MADE IT HERE!! -- destpath is :

2022-09-04 12:15:34.320552-0400 iRipCD[68991:3329339] destpath is : /Users/grinch/Downloads
```

FYI -- destpath is initilaized earler in the same file:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    task = nil;
    timer = nil;
    destpath = @"";
    taskOutput = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    fileList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:15];

    [(id) [NSApp delegate] setMaster:self];  // FIXED THIS!!  Added (id)

    return self;
}
```

Comment: [[oPanel URL] retain].path; may be the problem.  Try using [[oPanel URL] path];

Comment: Thanks for a tip.  But unfortunately, using `[[oPanel URL] path];` did not work.  I get the same behaviour.  I can verify that the code reaches oPanel, open ups the dialog for the user to select a destination directory, but for some reason the code does not wait for the user to select the directory.  The code moves on to the NSLog MADE IT HERE!! statement first.  Once the user selects the directory, the NSLog messages get displayed.  Very strange!

Comment: It looks like this problem has been mentioned before on stackoverflow but the solution was to use the deprecated method!  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369210/how-do-i-make-my-program-wait-for-nsopenpanel-to-close  I hope someone cam tell me how to do it without using the deprecated method.  Maybe, it be be done with `runModal` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one MUST use `runModal` to ensure that the NSOpenPanel object waits for the user to choose the directory.

The `beginWithCompletionHandler:` method does NOT wait for the user to finish his or her selection.

The following code appears to work:

```
if ([destpath isEqualToString:@""])
{
    NSOpenPanel *oPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [oPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
    [oPanel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
    [oPanel setCanChooseFiles:NO];

    // 
    // N.B. -- beginWithCompletionHandler: does not wait for the
    // user to finish with his or her selection!
    //               
    //[oPanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
    //     if(result == NSModalResponseOK) {
    //
    // Use runModal to ensure that the program waits for the user
    // to finish with his or her selection!
    //

    if ([oPanel runModal] == NSModalResponseOK)
    {
        destpath = [[[oPanel URL] path] retain]  // Also fixed memory bug!
        NSLog(@"destpath is : %@", destpath);
    }
    else
        return;         
 }
```